# Вывод картинок из папки PHP

Tags: php, вывод, изображения

Всем добрый день

Есть скрипт который выводим изображения из указанной папки, с этим он справляется отлично, но в этой папке два вида изображений, превью и оригинал и их надо выводить по отдельности, можете помочь их разделить и вывести

Превью начинаются с thumb1.jpg, 
Оригинал с page1.jpg

Мне нужно что бы вывести галерейку, например вот так:

```
<ul>
...
<li><a href="page1.jpg"><img src="thumb1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="page2.jpg"><img src="thumb2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="page3.jpg"><img src="thumb3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Сам скрипт

```
$directory     = './wp-content/plugins/real3d-flipbook/books/flipbook1'; //название папки с изображениями
$allowed_types = array(
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'gif',
    'png'
); //разрешеные типы изображений
$file_parts    = array();
$ext           = '';
$title         = '';
$i             = 0;
//пробуем открыть папку
$dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("There is an error with your image directory!");
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) //поиск по файлам
    {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
        continue; //пропустить ссылки на другие папки
    $file_parts = explode('.', $file); //разделить имя файла и поместить его в массив
    $ext        = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts)); //последний элеменет - это расширение
    if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types)) {
        echo '
    <img width="900" height="600" src="' . $directory . '/' . $file . '" class="attachment-slider wp-post-image" alt="img" title="img" />';
        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($dir_handle); //закрыть папку
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Так, а в чём проблема? Проверяйте имя файла, прежде чем выводить. Например, чтобы вывести все картинки, исключая превью, в вашем случае, добавьте:

```
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))    //поиск по файлам
{
    if (preg_match('/^thumb/', $file)) { //превью пропускаем
        continue;
    }
```

Или так:

```
if ($file=='.' || $file == '..' || preg_match('/^thumb/', $file)) continue;
```

Условия делайте, как вам нужно.